# C#, DevExpress and SQL multiple database table access problem

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio, devexpress

So pretty much I've started developing for a small company on a abandoned project they started like 2 years ago and I've hit a big roadblock. The app means to manage a lot of parameters and data of the buyer company, so there are a lot of datasets and tables but the single one that has given me a headache is this case:

I have a "Systems" table , with which I need to display info about the "Model" of a component, "VAT" ,"Unit of measure" and access a lot of data about the "Customer" , but the only columns the Systems table has are some System related strings and the ID's to the tables: Model,VAT, Unit of measure , Customer.

The UI has been designed by the guy that last worked on this so that the user could input a model string from a dropdown menu from the existing ones, and the VAT , unit of measure and name of the customer, but I can't really think of a way of making the Update,Insert and Delete queries as they cannot be generated automatically because of the use of multiple tables

I've tried a lot of ways of approaching this but always hit a dead end because something in my relational thinking of the tables wasn't good, (I hate SQL so don't judge) so please if someone has an idea I would be grateful

Comment: Bit too much of an open-ended question for [so], especially as you haven't provided any specific code you are struggling with. We'd love to help, but it's hard to see exactly what your issue is, or even what exactly you are coding (Back-end? UI? If UI which framework, WPF? WinForms? WebForms? Blazor? Something else?)

Comment: I'm using WinForms with devexpress. Here are some helpful links [link](https://imgur.com/a/FboMgha) , [link](https://imgur.com/a/LIf9GC4) , and the source code that is not yet ready: [link](https://codeshare.io/Qno8dW) .

Comment: This is a tricky thing for developing projects in small companies, and it is difficult to even have systematic information when taking over the project in the early stage. Usually in this case, I will add some temporary data to the database management tool to crud the data to familiarize myself with the database relationship